# Removing quotation marks around text in IntelliJ (with Regex?)

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, replace, language-agnostic

I have a piece of code where I want to remove the quotation marks around property names.

```
// Current format  
var user = {
   'name': 'A',
   'loggedIn': true
}

// Desired format
var user = {
   name: 'A',
   loggedIn: true
}
```

I've managed to find all the places I wish to change with this regular expression:

```
'(.+)'\:
```

Now I want to remove the quotation marks in those strings. I tried to enter `(.+)\:` into the "replace with" field, but it did not work. Is there some way to do what I want to do with this tool?

Comment: use `$1:` to replace your matched strings.

Comment: @MohaMad Your comment solved my issue. Could you post it as an answer and maybe elaborate how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Find in Path documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/find-and-replace-in-path.html) explains how to use the references:

- if you specify the search pattern through a regular expression, use the `$n` format in back references (to refer to a previously found and saved pattern).

`$1` will contain whatever is matched by the parenthesis, so your replacement string would look like `$1:`.

See also [Regular Expression Syntax Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches with your desire strings, but you missed using captured groups! `$1` returns first group and second and 3rd comes with `$2` and `$3` and ... .

Additional words:

You can back-referencing by `\1` in your find regex to avoid repeating capture groups codes.

I suggest use this regex instead of your own in general cases:

```
 ^\s*(['|"])(.*?)\1\s?:
```

and replace by `$2:` to extract string between '/".